# Intersection of two varieties in $\mathbf{F}_q^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, finite-fields

Suppose we identify $\mathbf{F}_q^n$ with $\mathbf{F}_{q^n}$. Let $X_n$ be the irreducible hypersurface defined by $Nx=1$ where $N$ is the norm map. There is an analogous hypersurface $X_{n-1}$ in $\mathbf{F}_q^{n-1}$. Embed $\mathbf{F}_q^{n-1}$ in $\mathbf{F}_q^n$ via your favourite linear map, so that $X_{n-1}$ becomes a codimension-2 variety in $\mathbf{F}_q^n$. Will $X_n \cap X_{n-1}$ be nonempty?

Morally I think that $X_n \cap X_{n-1}$ ought to be an irreducible variety of codimension $3$, which should therefore contain lots of points by Lang--Weil provided $n\geq 4$. But I don't know how to rule out $X_n \cap X_{n-1}$ being reducible.

Algebraic geometry is very far from my usual skill set, so please have mercy on me if this question is dumb.

Comment: In defining $X_{n-1}$, is the subspace $\mathbb{F}_1^{n-1}$ intended to be the kernel of the trace map?  Is $X_{n-1}$ the common zero locus of the norm and the trace?

Comment: @JasonStarr No, $X_{n-1}$ is the kernel of the norm map on $\mathbf{F}_{q^{n-1}}$, embedded in $\mathbf{F}_q^n$.

Comment: I assume you want to assume $n>2$? Because for $n=2$ there is an embedding where the intersection is empty (for $p>2$).

Comment: @user44191 I'm happy to assume $n$ is sufficiently large. My guess is that $n\geq 4$ is sufficient.

Comment: The problem with your question is  that it depens of so many choices (isomorphism of $\mathbb F_{q^n}$ and $\mathbb F_{q}^n$, immersion of $\mathbb F_{q}^{n-1}$ into $\mathbb F_{q}^n$) that it is difficult to give a clear answer...

Comment: @Xarles I agree. The arbitrary linear map $\mathbf{F}_q^{n-1} \to \mathbf{F}_q^n$ makes the question so unnatural that it feels impenetrable. The truth may be that there's no good reason the intersection should be irreducible. I should probably put some effort into producing a counterexample.

Comment: I'm not sure the question makes sense in the context of algebraic geometry - as stated, it's a question about finite sets. This doesn't really affect the part of the question dealing with nonemptiness, but I don't see how it makes sense to talk about irreducibility of finite sets without some specific definition of how to extend your varieties to some infinite field.

Comment: Is your question whether $X_n\cap X_{n-1}$ is irreducible for some choice of linear embedding, or for every choice?

Comment: @inkspot For every choice

Comment: There is a very quick partial result: if $p-1|n-1$, then the intersection is nonempty (and will have $\frac{p^{n-1}-1}{(p-1)^2}$ elements).